# How to add an NSMutableArray into NSMutableDictionary as a key?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array storing some attributes (those attributes are: tableID(string), tables coordinate(x,y coordinate in float)). Does anyone know how to store this array into `NSMutableDictionary`? And I need this `NSMutableDictionary` transfer into JSON string.

Comment: To convert a dictionary to JSON, all keys must be strings so you can't use an array as a key.

Comment: Keys for dictionaries must also be immutable.

Comment: oh.. this mean i cant add array into dictionary as a key? but this array is important to me because i got many tables attribute inside. i know how to convert all values inside to string, but i'm not sure how to use add array object to dictionary.

Comment: dreamlax - yup, my keys for dictionary will be immutable.

Comment: @dreamlax Keys do not need to be immutable though they usually are.

Comment: @ISAAC You can store the array in the dictionary but it must be stored as a value, not a key.

Comment: @rmaddy oh i get what you mean.. i store my array as value, and i set my key myself?

Comment: @ISAAC Sure, see the answer by Satish.

Comment: @rmaddy: They don't need to be strictly immutable, but they can't mutate in a way that affects `isEqual:` and `hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Simply set ur MUtable Array in MUtable Dictionary like

```
NSMutableDictionary *muteDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   [muteDict setObject:mutableArrayObject  forKey:@"YourKey"];
```

Comment: @ISAAC: FYI, this will actually create an immutable copy of the array rather than adding the mutable array itself as a key.